# Retrieve multiple recordsets from SQL in JSON format

Tags: javascript, sql, axios, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using SQL 2016 but I'm writing the JSON using Newtonsoft.Json because the wep api used to use SQL 2012.  I need to pull two record sets using javascript and Axio in a Vue application.  My Web API is currently

```
                    writer.WriteStartArray()
                    While reader.Read
                    writer.WriteStartObject()
                    writer.WritePropertyName("dbid")
                    writer.WriteValue(reader("dbid").ToString)

                    writer.WritePropertyName("memberID")
                    writer.WriteValue(reader("memberID").ToString)

                    writer.WriteEndObject()
                    End While
                    reader.NextResult()

                    writer.WriteEndArray()
                    writer.WriteStartArray()

                    While reader.Read
                    writer.WriteStartObject()
                    writer.WritePropertyName("ProgramCode")
                    writer.WriteValue(reader("ProgramCode").ToString)

                    writer.WritePropertyName("ProgramName")
                    writer.WriteValue(reader("ProgramName").ToString)

                    writer.WriteEndObject()
                   End While

                  writer.Close()
```

my output is

```
[{\"dbid\":\"100\",\"memberID\":\"1640\"},{\"dbid\":\"100\",\"memberID\":\"1641\"}][{\"ProgramCode\":\"CC\",\"Color\":\"Blue\"},{\"ProgramCode\":\"CB\",\"Color\":\"Green\"}]"
```

when I pass only one record set at a time I would

```
           this.$axios
    .get(
      "https://restapi2.azurewebsites.net/api/GetMembers/" +
        dbid
    )
    .then(res => {
       let result = JSON.parse(res.data);
```

and that would work fine and I would make two seperate calls to the database but it seems that I can't parse two arrays at one time.  I've tried

```
         let results = res.data[0];
         let result =  = JSON.parse(results[0]);
```

Am I doing this wrong?  I was hoping to only make one call to the database and set up two different arrays of values in the application.

Let me try to explain this a bit differently.

I have an Vue.js application that I need to populate 2 different arrays with data from a SQL server.  I have no problem filling the arrays with separate ajax/axios calls but what I want to do is to use one server call and split the data on the client side to the different arrays.  One array holds employee data and the other hold administration data.  Totally unrelatred.  If I was doing a .NET application I would just pull the record set as a datareader and do a readNext.

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand the result of the API call that you are getting, but here is a way of populating two different array of values from one dataset:

```
const data = [{name: "A", amount: 3}, {name: "B", amount: 12}, , {name: "C", amount: 1}];
let names = [];
let amounts = [];
data.forEach(function(d) {
  names.push(d.name);
  amounts.push(d.amount);
});
```

In case you have two datasets of the same length (and order) and want to set up two different arrays, here's a way:

```
const dataOne = [{name: "A"}, {name: "B"}, {name: "C"}];
const dataTwo = [{amount: 3}, {amount: 12}, {amount: 1}];
let names = [];
let amounts = [];
dataOne.forEach(function(d, idx) {
  names[idx] = d.name;
  amounts[idx] = dataTwo[idx].amount;
});
```

Comment: Thanks-- but I'm pulling two different dataset in one SQL query and I want to pass them to the client in one call and parse them client side.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution but boy does it stink and I really would like a more professional solution.

```
            let results = res.data.split("]");

             for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
             if (results[i].endsWith("]") == false) {
             results[i] = results[i] + "]";
             alert(results[i]); //for testing
             }
            }
```

First I split on the "]" which is the separator that ends each array and then treat each one separately by adding the closing array bracket.